# Building for iOS, but linking in dylib file built for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, macos-big-sur, xcode12.5

I updated my mac to macos big sur and my xcode to 12.5 and I am trying to run a react-native project on a real device but i get the error:

Building for iOS, but linking in dylib file (/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fvwvmhpisibgtserudvixobkmdfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL) built for iOS Simulator, file '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fvwvmhpisibgtserudvixobkmdfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL' for architecture arm64

I have seen many threads about the opposite thing, building for ios simulator... but not one for this issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ? This error pops every time I'm building the app for a real device. It drives me crazy.

Comment: Precisions : this happens to me only in Release mode. In Debug mode, I get a slightly different error error, but about another package : AppCenter. But I can't tell if I could pass through the OpenSSL error in Release mode, I'd get the appCenter error too.

Comment: I haven't found anything yet